# Using Min, Max and Count on HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, hql, min

Does hibernate HQL queries support using select min, max, count and other sql functions?

like:

`select min(p.age) from person p`

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

see topic 14.7.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `min()`, `max()` and `count()` are supported in HQL.

see [aggregate functions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-aggregate-functions) in the Hibernate Doc.

Comment: I had to downvote this answer, because it will quickly be deprecated. The answer gives the impression that only the three functions are present, when there are many others too

Answer (score 5):

thats how I am using max in Hibernate :

```
public long getNextId(){
long appId;         
try{
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getAdmSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
            String sequel = "Select max(JAdmAppExemptionId) from JAdmAppExemption";
            Query q = session.createQuery(sequel);
            List currentSeq = q.list();
            if(currentSeq == null){
                return appId;
            }else{
            appId = (Long)currentSeq.get(0);
            return appId+1;
            }

        }catch(Exception exc){
            System.out.print("Unable to get latestID");
            exc.printStackTrace();

        }
        return 0;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Some aggregate functions are supported: look in the [manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-aggregate-functions)

Comment: Unfortunately the link as changed. Can you re-retrieve the page? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Link fixed