# Max date in an nHibernate HQL query

Tags: nhibernate, hql, icriteria

I am having some difficultly writing an hql query that will search a table for all the rows where certain criteria are met but I only want to return the row with the max date.

For example the where clause of the query would be something like:

column1 = input1 and column2 = input2 and date_column < date_input

This might return several rows with different dates but I am only interested in the one with the latest date.  I also need it to return the entire row.

Presently, I am executing the query with the criteria above ordered descending by date and then fetching the first item in C#.  I would like to have an hql query or iCriteria solution that can do this in one step if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use a subquery. Select the max date from the qualifying rows and then select out all records which match the max date. My HQL is a little rusty but you get the idea.

```
from TableA a 
where a.Date in (
    select max(b.Date) 
    from TableA b 
    where b.Something="You get the idea"
)
```

[Subqueries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713068/nhibernate-hql-subselect-queries), [Aggregate Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330918/using-min-max-and-count-on-hql)

Comment: This is grabbing all of the rows from TableA that have a date equal to the date selected by the sub-query, so the where criteria in the sub-query are not applied to the main query.

Comment: I was assuming the dates were unique. Why don't you just apply the `where` criteria to both the main query and the subquery?